# Send model via jquery ajax call to dialog box

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

And i have this edit button :

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "Edit", new { oid = item.memoOID }, new { id = "edit_" + item.memoOID })
```

I would like to populate the entity from the controller action "Edit" and send it to a dialog box defined below ( i want it to replace the new Domain.Model.memo() :

```
<div id="memoAddDialog" title="New Memo" style="display: none">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Pat/newMemoDialog.cshtml", new Domain.Model.memo())
</div>
```

With this popup :

```
function OpenMemoDialog() {
        $("#memoAddDialog").dialog("open");
    }

    $("#memoAddDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 575,
        width: 900,
        dialogClass: "positioning24"
    });
```

I just dont know how to pass the value to that partial view and need some pointers; can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
  //In View 
    @Ajax.ActionLink("AjaxLink", "Edit", new { oid = item.memoOID ,id = "edit_"+item.memoOID }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "memoAddDialog", HttpMethod = "Post",OnSuccess="Success" })

    <div id="memoAddDialog" title="New Memo" style="display: none">
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function Success()
{
  //open your dialogbox here
   $("#memoAddDialog").dialog("open");
}

</script>
```

In Controller

```
[httpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(string oid , string id)
{
     //perform your functionality 

    return PartialView("~/Views/Patient/newMemoPatientDialog.cshtml", new Mavi.Domain.Model.memo());
}
```

NOTE: In Ajax.ActionLink you must provide **UpdateTargetId** where you result will appear on Page

Comment: yes .. i deleted the ajax options ... for space purposes... they are all there ... This solution is closer to my needs ... Gonna implement it and let you know if i have any troubles doing it .

Comment: Awesome .. worked like a charm .. sorry took so long .. better to solve it all by myself :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
<a href="OpenMemoDialog('@(Url.Action("Edit", new oid = item.memoOID)')" />
```

with OpenMemoDialog as:

```
function OpenMemoDialog(url) {
        $("#memoAddDialog").dialog("open");
        $("#memoAddDialog").load(url);
    }
```

memoAddDialog is just an empty div & your Edit action should return the partial view.

Comment: any chance i could use actionlink for that ? Its a dynamically created table .. and i have many other jquery calls on it

Comment: sorry Mihai i am not getting you point ca you please explain it in brief.